# Ограничение ввода данных в зависимости от состояния QCheckBox

Tags: python, gui, pyqt, pyside2, qcheckbox

Создан класс-окно, в нем  есть `QCheckBox` и `QLineEdit`. 
В зависимости от состояния `QCheckBox` нужно ограничить ввод цифр в `QLineEdit` следующим образом: 
если `QCheckBox.isChecked()`, то при вводе цифр в `QLineEdit` появлялось сообщение **`warning("Значение не может быть меньше 15")`** и можно было бы ввести цифры только больше **`15`**.

Я планировал сделать так:

```
class MainWnd(QMainWindow, mainGui.Ui_RecistMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWnd, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.exitApp)
        self.actionNew_subject.triggered.connect(self.newsubj_clicked)
        self.baseline_btn.clicked.connect(self.baseline_clicked)
        self.actionExport.triggered.connect(self.export_action_triggered)
        self.actionEdit_BS.triggered.connect(self.edit_bs)

    def edit_bs(self):
        dialogbs = BaseLine(self.id_label.text())
        if dialogbs.exec_():
            for rows in range(0, 3):
                self.tableWidget.removeRow(0) ...

    def newsubj_clicked(self, parent=None):
        dialog = NewSubject()
        if dialog.exec_():
            self.id_label.setText(dialog.createid_lineedit.text())
            self.id_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
            self.baseline_btn.setEnabled(True)

    def baseline_clicked(self):
        dialogbs = BaseLine(self.id_label.text())
        if dialogbs.exec_():
            self.actionEdit_BS.setEnabled(True) ...

    def exitApp(self):
        sys.exit(0)


class NewSubject(QDialog, newidGui.Ui_newSubjId):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NewSubject, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.createid_lineedit.setFocus()


class BaseLine(QDialog, baselineGui.Ui_BaseLine):
    def __init__(self, id_value, parent=None):
        super(BaseLine, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.id_label_baseline.setText(id_value)
        self.id_label_baseline.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)

        if self.lineEdit < 15 and self.target1_type.isChecked():
            QMessageBox.warning(self, __appname__, 'Nodal lesion should be >= 15 mm in short axis.')
```

Собственно в последнем окне нужно сделать ограниченный ввод данных. 
Я пробовал вот так:

```
if self.lineEdit < 15 and self.target1_type.isChecked():
    QMessageBox.warning(self, __appname__, 'Nodal lesion should be >= 15 mm in short axis.')
```

Но видимо перехватывать нужно раньше?
Пока не пойму как и где?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то для ввода чисел предназначен `QSpinBox`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.spinBox.setRange(-100, 1000)
        self.spinBox.setValue(7)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.onValueChanged)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Значение SpinBox: {}".format(self.spinBox.value()))

        self.checkBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("минимальное значение спин-бокса 15") 
        self.checkBox.setChecked(False)
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.onStateChanged)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(self.label,    0, 0, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(self.spinBox,  1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.checkBox, 1, 1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onStateChanged(self, state):
        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.spinBox.setMinimum(15)
        else: 
            self.spinBox.setMinimum(-100)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onValueChanged(self, v):
        self.label.setText("Значение SpinBox: {}".format(v))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.setWindowTitle('Test CheckBox-SpinBox')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Выкрутился путем создания функции с исключениями:

```
class BaseLine(QDialog, baselineGui.Ui_BaseLine):

def __init__(self, id_value, parent=None):
    super(BaseLine, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.id_label_baseline.setText(id_value)
    self.id_label_baseline.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)


def accept(self):

    class GreaterThan(Exception): pass
    class LessThan(Exception): pass


    try:
        if self.target1_type.isChecked() and int(self.lineEdit.text()) < 15: #ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
            raise GreaterThan, ('Nodal lesion should be >= 15 mm in short axis')
        elif int(self.lineEdit.text()) < 10 and not self.target1_type.isChecked() :
            raise LessThan, ('Non-nodal lesion should be >= 10 mm in long axis')
        else:
            self.connect(self.buttonBox.Ok, accepted(), BaseLine.accept)


    except GreaterThan, e:
        QMessageBox.warning(self, __appname__, str(e))
        self.lineEdit.clear()
        self.target1_type.setFocus()
        return

    except LessThan, e:
        QMessageBox.warning(self, __appname__, str(e))
        self.lineEdit.clear()
        self.target1_type.setFocus()
        return
```

но появилась следуюющая проблема суть которой изложу еще в одном вопросе